# Try to find a way to fit an extremely large index into memory

Tags: mysql, ejabberd, database-partitioning

**Description:**

I am having trouble with the on-growing data size in my MySQL database.

I am using Ejabberd and MAM function which will make use of an `archive` table to store messages sent between users and the table keeps growing. It now takes over 10 seconds to query something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM archive WHERE username = '<some_id>' and bare_peer = '<some_string>' and timestamp >= '<some_timestamp_in_microseconds'
```

or

```
SELECT timestamp, XML, peer, kind, nick FROM archive WHERE username = '<some_id>' and bare_peer = '<some_string>' and timestamp >= '<some_timestamp_in_microseconds>' and timestamp <= '<some_timestamp_in_microseconds>'
```

These are very common SQL that would execute thousands of times each day, and since the SQL are executed from within Ejabberd, I cannot change the syntax.

**Current Situation:**

- Instance Specification: 8 core CPU, 64 GB RAM
  innodb_buffer_pool_size: 49392123904 bytes (roughly around 49GB)
- With references to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194) post, I got the result of 1005383M (roughly 1TB) estimated requirement of memory size.
- The archive table size: 700GB of data, and ~200GB of index, around 0.9b of rows (yes, a lot of rows)
- Here is the table creation SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `archive` (
  `username` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `peer` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bare_peer` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `xml` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `txt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kind` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `i_username` (`username`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `i_timestamp` (`timestamp`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `i_peer` (`peer`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `i_bare_peer` (`bare_peer`) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT KEY `i_text` (`txt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Discussion:**

With the below information, one thing I could think of is to:

- Partition the archive table with Primary Key (RANGE / Per 5m of rows), but from my understanding, since MySQL doesn't support fulltext index in Partitions, I would be required to drop the fulltext index in the txt column, which I think is ok.
- Unfortunately, since MySQL could only partition on Primary Keys, and I cannot change the SQL. I therefore cannot utilize the partition directly on the SQL. What I could do is to drop the entire partition regularly and keep the remaining index size to fit into memory as much as possible.

I am posting to seek for a second opinion on whether:

1. Is this the best way I could do with the above limitations?
2. If so, How can I partition such a big table without downtime, by using possibility [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html) ?

Thank you all for your time.

**Update**

**Result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE archive;`**

```
CREATE TABLE `archive` (
   `username` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `timestamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `peer` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `bare_peer` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `xml` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `txt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
   `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `kind` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `nick` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
   KEY `i_username` (`username`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `i_timestamp` (`timestamp`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `i_peer` (`peer`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `i_bare_peer` (`bare_peer`) USING BTREE,
   FULLTEXT KEY `i_text` (`txt`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1380855687 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Result of `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'archive'`**

```
           Name: archive
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 861904436
 Avg_row_length: 889
    Data_length: 766958911488
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 250423246848
      Data_free: 7340032
 Auto_increment: 1380860914
    Create_time: 2017-06-06 08:02:54
    Update_time: 2020-06-07 12:07:27
     Check_time: 
      Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
       Checksum: 
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 
1 rows in set
```

Update 2:

Explain for the first query

```
******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: archive
   partitions: 
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: i_username,i_timestamp,i_bare_peer
          key: i_bare_peer,i_username
      key_len: 766,766
          ref: 
         rows: 10
     filtered: 1.08
        Extra: Using intersect(i_bare_peer,i_username); Using where
1 rows in set
```

Explain for the second query

```
******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: archive
   partitions: 
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: i_username,i_timestamp,i_bare_peer
          key: i_bare_peer,i_username
      key_len: 766,766
          ref: 
         rows: 10
     filtered: 1.16
        Extra: Using intersect(i_bare_peer,i_username); Using where; Using filesort
1 rows in set
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of 'SHOW CREATE TABLE archive;' for us to verify you have NO PRIMARY key and to see current indexes available.  The indexes could have changed since creation of the table many days ago.  Have you considered limiting the indexes of username, peer and bare_peer to less than 191 varchar?  Are you aware your application will not run after Jan, 2038 when you use datetype of timestamp?  Due to timestamp range limit per the reference manual.

Comment: Could you also post TEXT results of 'SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'archive';  Thanks

Comment: Please see the updated content. @WilsonHauck Yes there is no Primary Key, the timestamp is actually a bigint and contain values in microseconds. Limiting the index might help but since the index size is over so much, limiting might not be significant?

Comment: And the `created_at` field could be dropped in the future since that is just a reference.

Comment: Could you post TEXT of A) the first query with B) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE rest of your first query;  C) the second query with D) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE rest of your second query; ?  Are you familiar with an index composed of multiple columns?  It looks like you need combination of username, bare_peer, timestamp to reduce your 10 second response time.  Is there any reason the column named id could not be promoted to PRIMARY which could cause the other indexes to become smaller in storage required?

Comment: Using reserved names for column names is hazardous because of the confusion it causes - timestamp could be d_r_microseconds to represent data row microseconds - name the column for what it represents.

Comment: Please see the updates. Sorry for the confusion, that's the default Ejabberd MySQL Schema structure. I understand where you are going, by adding `username, bare_peer, timestamp` as a composite index to speed up the search. But my concern is, even I got the index right, with the given size 200GB of index, it seems that the size could not fit into the memory. I also wish to think of a way to properly manage the storage size, like on retain the data for the pass 6 months in the future.

Comment: How long did it take these two queries to complete?  What version of MySQL are you running?  SELECT @@version;  Do you have flexibility to use Skype TALK - in English?  My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com